# 'infer' vs 'extrapolate'

Tags: verbs, synonyms

The two examples are taken from [OALD:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/extrapolate)

> We have **extrapolated** these results from research done in other
>   countries.
>
> The results cannot be **extrapolated** to other patient groups.

Could I substitute **infer** for **extrapolate** here? I think they are synonyms. Any nuances implied?

Comment: Putting syntactically issues aside, *extrapolate* is something numerical to me, whereas *infer* is more about something logical. The distinction is not that clear-cut, though.

Comment: Not necessarily. One could extrapolate truth, I suppose. @DamkerngT.

Comment: That's why I think the difference is not clear-cut. However, I think I tend to allow myself to say "extrapolate" something (like an opinion or a conclusion) only when it's an extrapolation from numerical data.

Comment: @DamkerngT. nails it. *Interpolation* and *extrapolation* are mathematical operations, predicting unknown values from the curve defined by known values. *Inference* is a logical operation, drawing conclusions from established premises.

Comment: I know that interpolation is mathematical operation because it's often used for rate calculations in financial management. But I have indeed come across **extrapolate** being used semantically the same way as **infer**. How is that? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng *Extrapolate* is used a little more loosely in this sense (from M-W): "extend the application of (a method or conclusion, especially one based on statistics) to an unknown situation by assuming that existing trends will continue or similar methods will be applicable." But use to mean *infer* is simply a mistake by writers who don't know what the word means.

Comment: Got it! Thx. @StoneyB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to see "extrapolate" as a sub-type of "infer."

"Infer" can refer to small abductions that aren't always as well supported. One can infer emotions in the speaker, but not extrapolate emotions. It's not uncommon for a heated discussion to feature an accusation of "You implied (X)!" and response of "I did not! You inferred that!"

"Extrapolate" generally refers to statistical or logical inferences and tends to indicate a more scientific and controlled context. The product of extrapolation (the extrapolated information) is generally larger quantitatively or qualitatively, whereas "infer" can be is more limited. The [etymology of "extrapolate"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=extrapolate) points to looking at patterns within some set and reproducing those patterns outside the set as a prediction, which should reinforce that "extrapolate" is a term used in more logical and quantitative speech.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against in the first case. Infer does fit in this sentence properly, but in research contexts extrapolate is the correct word to use if you want to say you used results from other research and applied it to the situation in question.

In the second case, infer is not acceptable at all. "Infer to" is not used as the opposite of "infer from".

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolation is a "weak" form of inference. So, in the second sentence, something that cannot be extrapolated also cannot be inferred.

Extrapolation means, we have seen such-and-such results, at such and such intervals in the past (without knowing why). Based on past "intervals," we are "due" for another occurrence of these results.

Inference means, we have seen such-and-such results in the past following presence of such-and-such *causal variables* (the why). (E.g., rain has usually followed the gathering of dark clouds in the sky). Based on the return of these causal variables (dark clouds), we predict the return of the consequent results (rain).